# Importing python module, through __init__.py script

Tags: python, import

My directory structure is

```
app.py
lib
   __init__.py
   _foo.py
```

Inside `__init__.py` I have written

```py
from . import _foo as foo
```

Then inside `app.py` I try to make a call

```py
from lib.foo import *
```

but it throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.foo'` exception.

Basically I want to import everything from `_foo.py`, through the `__init__.py` script.
While I realize the code works if `_foo.py` is renamed into `foo.py`, 
I still wonder if there is any way to make import work through `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about hacking around the import statements, but you could get away with something less explicit like this:

`lib/__init__.py`

```py
from . import _foo as foo

__all__ = ['foo']
```

`lib/_foo.py`

```py
__all__ = [
    'test'
]

test = 1
```

```
>>> from lib import *
>>> foo
<module 'lib._foo' from '/path/to/test/lib/_foo.py'>
>>> foo.test
1
>>>
```

EDIT: You could achieve something more explicit by updating sys.modules at runtime:

`app.py`

```
import sys
from lib import _foo

sys.modules['lib.foo'] = _foo
```

`lib/_foo.py`

```
test = 1
```

keep `lib/__init__.py` to make lib a module

After importing app `lib.foo` will be an available module

```
>>> import app
>>> from lib import foo
>>> foo
<module 'lib._foo' from '/path/to/test/lib/_foo.py'>
>>> foo.test
1
```

Comment: Thanka for introducing me to `__all__`, didn,t know it existed until now :) Though this is somewhat too implicit